# Using python, copy a file to a folder that has almost the same name as the file

Tags: python, copy

I will try to explain what I'm trying to do, but English isn't my first language.

I have a list of items, e.g. `["cat size", "house size", "car size"]`
and some files that contain the names of the items in my list. e.g. `cat.size.txt` and `house.size.fromBob.txt`.

I want to do the following copy: `cat.size.txt` to directoty `H:/new/2CopyTo/Cat size/` and `house.size.fromBob.txt` to directory `H:/new/2CopyTo/house size/`

Below is what I made to copy the files to just one directory, but I want each file in its own directory (on my pc the list contains 50 items, so don't want to do it manually).

Thanks!!

```
import glob
import shutil
import os

#=========List of items
list = ["cat size","house size","car size"]

#=========directories
FromDir = "H:/New/1RecievedFiles/"
CopyDir = "H:/New/2CopyTo/"

#=========get list of items to be used in glob.glob
filesList = [x.replace(" ", "*")+"*.*" for x in list]

#=========get list of new files in FromDir, use filesList in glob.glob
listOfNew = [glob.glob(FromDir+item) for item in filesList ]
# returns [['H:/New/1RecievedFiles\\cat.size.txt'], ['H:/New/1RecievedFiles\\house.size.fromBob.txt']]    

#=========make a single list from the list in a list
listOfNewfiles = [item for sublist in listOfNew for item in sublist]
# returns ['H:/New/1RecievedFiles\\cat.size.txt', 'H:/New/1RecievedFiles\\house.size.fromBob.txt']

#=========copy files
[shutil.copy2(item, CopyDir) for item in listOfNewfiles]
```

Comment: Your code formatting and your handling of English are both excellent, by the way.

Comment: I completely agree with Two-Bit.  Code organization like that makes for the easiest and fastest debugging and code modification.  Most issues you come across never make it here I'll bet since you can probably usually see exactly where the problem is.  Bravo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set up a test directory that looks like this:

```
$ ls -1
copyto/
car.size.txt
cat.size.txt
house.size.fromBob.txt
```

I believe this is similar to what you have. Given the same list you have, here is how I approached your problem:

```
import os, shutil
# lst not list -- naming it list overshadows a builtin
lst = ['cat size', 'house size', 'car size']
# PEP8 - lowercase with underscore here; CamelCase for classes
from_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser('~/test'))
copy_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser('~/test/copyto'))

to_copy = [f for f in os.listdir(from_dir) if os.path.isfile(f)]
# ['car.size.txt', 'house.size.fromBob.txt', 'cat.size.txt']

for filename in to_copy:
    needle = ' '.join(filename.split('.')[:2])
    if needle in lst:
        dest_dir = os.path.join(copy_dir, needle)
        os.mkdir(dest_dir)
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(from_dir, filename), dest_dir)
```

After this, my `test` directory was exactly as shown before, and this is the result of `ls -R1 copyto`:

```
copyto:
car size/
cat size/
house size/

copyto/car size:
car.size.txt

copyto/cat size:
cat.size.txt

copyto/house size:
house.size.fromBob.txt
```

Does that work for your case? (PS - Python is great for this kind of thing, isn't it?)

Comment: Thanks so mush, I had to look at it closely to understand (I'm not very knowledgeable in python yet) but it will work. I agree 100% python is great for this, actually it is fantastic I have only worked with it for the 5 months now and I love it.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your list and check for the term that categorizes where its going to be saved.  I.E. 'cat', 'dog', or 'house'

something like this

```
import os,shutil

for item in list:
    if 'cat' in listitem:
        shutil.copyfile(source, 'H:/new/2CopyTo/cat size/')
    elif 'house' in listitem:
        shutil.copyfile(source, 'H.......etc etc
    elif 'car'.....
```

is this what you were wanting?

Comment: No real need for a hard-coded `if/elif/else` tree here. We can use the relation of the filenames to the destination directories (see my answer).

Comment: You're absolutely right.  You're solution is better. I was hesitant because without the actual list i worried it could contain things like 'ford.ranger' and 'midsize.sedan' that would also need to be in the 'car size' folder.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually very nice and I will make a note of it. I just have a long list so I want to try do automate it, currently I have a bat file that copy every thing but to maintain it is a pain. Thanks